# File Upload with Retry Count and Retry Delay -Best Approach in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, ssh

I have a case there i want upload files  with Retry count and Retry delay

Currently i am doing upload like

```
Status UploadWithRetry(string sourceFile, string destinationFolder, int retryCount, int retryIntervalSeconds)
    {

        Status uploadStatus = new FileTransferStatus { FilePath = sourceFile };

        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
        {

                _client.UploadFile(fileStream, destinationFilePath, null);
                 Status.Success = true;
                return uploadStatus;
            }
        }

    }
```

How can i modify it to include logic for Retry count and retry delay. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Can you explain what frameworks and techs you are using and what exactly you want to do? Do you want to provide the backend with max attempts to retry or do you want to front end to count how many times you retried?

Comment: i am using ssh client. But what i require is retry and delay need to apply in _client.UploadFile(fileStream, destinationFilePath, null).. if any exception happens(ie._client.UploadFile),it should retry based on delay parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recurrsion and to delay the next try use Task.Delay(..).Wait()
Something like the following

```
Status UploadWithRetry(string sourceFile, string destinationFolder, int retryCount, int retryIntervalSeconds)
{

    Status uploadStatus = new FileTransferStatus { FilePath = sourceFile };

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);

    var status = default(Status);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
    {

            _client.UploadFile(fileStream, destinationFilePath, null);
             Status.Success = true;

            status = uploadStatus;
        }
    }
    if (retryCount == 0)
        return status;
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryIntervalSeconds)).Wait();
    return UploadWithRetry(sourceFile, destinationFolder, retryCount - 1, retryIntervalSeconds);
}
```

Edit:
I would mix sanders answer with mine, I didn't include the try..catch..finaly in mine which he did

Edit2:
If you take the UploadFile from sander and use the following it should work great

```
    Status UploadWithRetry(string sourceFile, string destinationFolder, int retryCount, int retryIntervalSeconds)
    {
        var status = UploadFile(sourceFile);

        if (status.Success)
            return status;

        if (retryCount == 0) //OR THROW EXCEPTION HERE
            return status;
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryIntervalSeconds)).Wait();
        return UploadWithRetry(sourceFile, destinationFolder, retryCount - 1, retryIntervalSeconds);
    }
```

Comment: @Sander .Also i want to throw exception which happens in last retry attempt

Comment: Well what you could do is put in a check that in the main method, but I would refrain from throwing exceptions.

Comment: Edit my answer if you want to throw exception do it there

Comment: Or as sander suggestion to add a property message, you really shouldn't throw exceptions

Comment: @Donald Jansen .. it is brilliant after combining two logic ..recursive solution looks great

Comment: I am glad that we could help.

Answer (score 3):

I would refactor your code this way:

```
Status UploadWithRetry(string sourceFile, string destinationFolder, int maxRetryCount, int retryIntervalSeconds)
{      

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
    var uploadAttempts = 0;
    var success = false;
    var status = new FileTransferStatus { FilePath = sourceFile };
    while(uploadAttempts < maxRetryCount && !success){
        status = UploadFile(sourceFile);
        uploadAttempts++;
        success = status.Success;
    }
    if(uploadAttempts >= maxRetryCount){
        //throw new Exception(); //I would advise against this
        status.Message = "Max retry attempts reached."; //display this message to the frontend
    }
    return status;
}

Status UploadFile(string sourceFile){
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
            Status uploadStatus = new FileTransferStatus { FilePath = sourceFile };
            try{

                _client.UploadFile(fileStream, destinationFilePath, null);
                Status.Success = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Status.Success = false;
            }
            return uploadStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

For your delay you could use thread.sleep but or use some kind of timer. I hope this helps you on your way.
EDIT: I like a mix of my answer with Donald Jansen's answer!

Comment: Thx, just updated my answer with the advice to mix our answers. I like your recursive solution... a lot!

Comment: Haha I did the same. I like the UploadFile to return a status, which can be used in my recursive

Comment: @Sander .Also i want to throw exception which happens in last retry attempt

Comment: I edited the answer. In this case you need to add a string Message to your Status class which you can use to communicate back to the front end.

Comment: If we need to call this retry function at specific interval,i.e after retryIntervalSeconds. what changes are required?

Comment: Hi Priya, see the answer of Donald Jansen above!